# Django, consulta sumatoria de una tabla a otra contectada foranea

Tags: django, django-models

Tendo los siguientes modelos:

```
class Articulo(models.Model):
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=80)
   costo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places= 2)
   precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places= 2)   
   familia = models.ForeignKey(Familia)

def unidades(self):
    n = self.Movimiento.all().count()
    return str(n)

class Movimiento(models.Model):
    articulo = models.ForeignKey(Articulo)
    almacen = models.ForeignKey(Almacen)
    entidad = models.ForeignKey(Entidad)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    entrada = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    salida = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    costo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, default= 0.0)
    importe = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

Lo que realmente quiero que el def unidades del Articulo diga la resta de unidades de todos los movimientos de su articulo (entrada - salida)

He puesto lo de count() haciendo pruebas, pero fallan todas.

Comment: debes usar `self.movimiento_set.all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una forma de hacerlo usando funciones nativas de python. Recuerda que para acceder al conjunto de instancias que te referencian debes usar `class_set` donde `class` es el nombre del modelo *referenciador*. Entonces sería `self.movimiento_set.all()`

```
def unidades(self):
    movimientos = self.movimiento_set.all()
    unidades = sum(map(lambda m: m.entrada - m.salida, movimientos))
    return unidades
```

Comment: Necesito aprender lambda. Usé _set por mi cuenta pero no consguí nada. Muchas gracias por la yuda.